# I have a column starttimeGMT which contains date in format 2021-03-31T14:30:27+00:00.I need to extract the portion 14:30:27 in sql.How can I get it

Tags: sql

I have tried using parse_timestamp but was not able to get it.Please help me find a query for this

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Are you using BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

To get a piece of string you can use SUBSTRING, for example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(starttimeGTM, 12, 29) FROM tableName
```